# Why is the fivestar rating displaying/suggesting 4 out of 5 stars when no votes have been made?

Tags: rating

When adding a node which has a fivestar field and there are no votes yet, it shows 4 out of 5 stars as "on". Is this intended/ normal?

In my `preprocess_page` hook:

```
<?php
if (isset($node->field_rating)) {
                $field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_rating', array('label' => 'hidden'));
                $rating = render($field);
                $vars['title_rating'] = $rating;
            }
```

which gets rendered like this (with no votes made yet):

```
<div class="fivestar-widget clearfix fivestar-widget-5">
    <div class="cancel">
            <a href="#0" title="Cancel rating">Cancel rating</a>
    </div>
    <div class="star star-1 odd star-first on">
            <a href="#20" title="Give it 1/5">Give it 1/5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="star star-2 even on">
            <a href="#40" title="Give it 2/5">Give it 2/5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="star star-3 odd on">
            <a href="#60" title="Give it 3/5">Give it 3/5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="star star-4 even on">
            <a href="#80" title="Give it 4/5">Give it 4/5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="star star-5 odd star-last">
            <a href="#100" title="Give it 5/5">Give it 5/5</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I've made a workaround putting a class and set "display: none" in it.